# yii CSqlDataProvider's pagination is not working

Tags: php, mysql, yii, pagination

i'm using mysql commands to do the query in yii, i want the item in cart to be listed in cart's view page.

it works fine with showing the items'number on the top and some pagination link at the bottom. but all the item is showing in one page, pagination not work.

controller/cartController.php:

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE cart_id=$id";
    $count=Cart::getItemCount($id);
    $dataProvider=new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array(
        'totalItemCount'=>$count,
        'pagination'=>array(
                    'pageSize'=>5,
        ),
    ));
    $this->render('view',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}
```

View/cart/view.php:

```
<?php $this->widget('booster.widgets.TbListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_problems_view',
)); ?>
```

Comment: Rid of the `;` at the end of the query.

Comment: Please show the getItemCount() body

Answer (score 0):

I also facing this issues and solved them by removing ; at the end of the query.